# How to ignore undefined variable when import variable from file in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, variable-assignment

I have imported some variables from python file, example:

**myvariables.py**

```
USERNAME_TEXTBOX = '//android.widget.TextView/[@text= "Username"]'
PASSWORD_TEXTBOX = '//android.widget.TextView/[@text= "Password"]'
LOGIN_BUTTON = '//android.widget.TextView/[@text= "Login"]'
```

**test_login.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library         AppiumLibrary
Resource        resource.robot
Variables       myvariables.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test Login Successfully
    Open App
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${USERNAME_TEXTBOX}
    Input Text    ${USERNAME_TEXTBOX}   ${USERNAME}
    Input Text    ${PASSWORD_TEXTBOX}   ${PASSWORD}
    Click Element    ${LOGIN_BUTTON}
```

I don't define that variable again at `*** Variables ***` in Robot file because my test case run successfully without define again and my code will be shorter. But in the workspace, those variables (which were import from `myvariables.py`) are marked with red color (undefined variable), it's quite annoying.

[HIGHLIGHT IN THE WORKSPACE] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9wBe.png)

[PROBLEM] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX30P.png)

So how can I ignore that?

Comment: What editor are you using? I have a similar problem, except I inject variables through ROBOT_OPTIONS. My workaround is to define them in *** Variables *** section.

Comment: @Pekka I'm using VSCode. I think every IDE has this problem

Comment: I am using Robot Code plugin in VSCode, and it has setting `@id:robotcode.robot.variables` where you can pre-defined variables.